# Add two values that return from API

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, external-services

I'm going to be calling a REST endpoint to return back data for two datapoints into a lightning component in SF. This is only needed from a UI standpoint visually on the lightning component.

This may be more of a general question. Is there a way to add External data point 1  + external data point 2 and show that sum . e.g. 10+10= 20 .  Since we are calling a REST endpoint externally , not sure if SF is able to add those two or if it's dependent on getting the sum of those amounts externally.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a component, you can script this a number of ways. For example:

```
let values = await Promise.all(
  [method1(), method2()]
)
let sum = values.reduce((accum, value) => accum + value, 0)
```

You could also accomplish this in a Flow, as well.